# Using of Smart Pointers on objects with automatic storage duration

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Is it a problem if I apply Smart Pointers (`scoped_ptr`, `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`) on objects with automatic storage duration (i.e. stored on the stack)? I assume not as in both cases (with and without smart pointers) they will be deleted if no more pointers pointing on them. Pointers themself have always automatic storage duration, i.e. they will be deleted if they go out of scope.

Comment: You could as long as you also include a custom deleter that doesn't delete the object...

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, there is a problem (a big one): you are using smart pointers to do something (I don't know what) they were not designed to do. They are meant to manage the lifetime of dynamically allocated objects. They solve a problem inherited from `C`, they offer ownership to objects which need dynamic allocation/release (they aren't restricted to memory (pointers); you can actually use smart pointers to manage any type of resource which needs acquire/release, e.g. system resources, file descriptors, etc).

Ok, but aside from the philosophical problem, is there a practical problem?

**Yes!!**. A smart pointer will call `delete` / `delete[]` on the owned object, which is Undefined Behavior when the pointer is not obtained from `new` / `new[]` respectively.

And yes, you can use a custom deleter that does nothing, but then what was the point of using smart pointers anyway?

Comment: What's the point of a using a smart_ptr with do-nothing deleter? Suppose you have a `map<shared_ptr<X>, Y>`, indexed by `int X::id_` because so most of the class logic dictates (might be even in a lib you cannot change). Now, you want to find the `Y` that corresponds to a certain `int id` value. What you can do is to create a dummy `X` on the stack with the key set to your `id` (and the rest of attr to default) *with a do-nothing deleter*, perform the search and be happy (instead of iterating the map - which may not even be accessible - or allocate the `X` from heap)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [demo](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/KEguL3) :

```
class Foo{
    public:
        Foo(){cout << "Foo created!\n";}
        ~Foo(){cout << "Foo destroyed!\n";}
};
void go(){
    Foo foo;
    cout << "Position A\n";
    {
        Foo foo1;
    }
    cout << "Position B\n";
    {
        Foo *foo2;
    }
    cout << "Position C\n";
    {
        Foo *foo3 = new Foo;
    }
    cout << "Position D\n";
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo3(new Foo);
    }
    cout << "Position E\n";
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo3(&foo);
    }
    cout << "Position F\n";
}
```

Gives output as:

```
Foo created!
Position A
Foo created!
Foo destroyed!
Position B
Position C
Foo created!
Position D
Foo created!
Foo destroyed!
Position E
Foo destroyed!
```

ends with

**Runtime error:
Error : free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffda60f0e67**

Notice the difference between Positions D-E and Positions E-F (deleting a pointer that didn't come from **new**, so results in *undefined behavior*).

Comment: Please share with us where did you use a custom do-nothing deleter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a problem as the smart pointer will (ignoring custom deleters for now) call `delete` on an object that was not created via `new` (which is UB) and the destructor will be called twice (which results in undefined behavior too).

It will btw. also lead to errors if you try to manage an object via two independent smart pointers.

So, where lifetime management is concerned, *"The more the merrier"* is definitely not true.