# free(): invalid pointer when using get() instead of release() on unique_ptr

Tags: c++, stack, unique-ptr

I have the following program:

```
#include <list>
#include <stack>  
#include <memory>

struct ChildNode {};

struct value_node_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<ChildNode> {
    using std::unique_ptr<ChildNode>::unique_ptr;
    using std::unique_ptr<ChildNode>::reset;
};

struct Node {
    std::list<value_node_ptr> children;
    void addChild(ChildNode* child){
        children.emplace_back(child);
    }
};

void iterateChildren(Node* node){
    for(auto it=node->children.begin(); it != node->children.end(); ++it){
        auto child = it->release();
        //do stuff with child
    }
}

int main() {
    ChildNode child;
    Node node;
    node.addChild(&child);

    std::stack<Node*> nodes;
    nodes.push(&node);
    iterateChildren(nodes.top());

    nodes.pop();
}
```

This works fine. But if I am using `it->get()` instead of `it->release()` in the `iterateChildren` function, I get the error

```
free(): invalid pointer
```

I want to reuse the children at some point and I thought `it->release()` would destruct the pointer so it won't be usable after, but it seems the pointer is still there, which confuses me.

Furthermore I thought `it->get()` was the way to go as I just want to get the value and not destruct the pointer. I was thinking that there might be some memory-leak kind of error when calling `it->get()`, which is why I tried calling `it->reset()` on each of the children after being done using them, but this did not resolve the error either.

Can someone explain me this behaviour as well as which method I am supposed to use?

Comment: You are using a `unique_ptr` as a pointer to an *automatic storage* ChildNode object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using of Smart Pointers on objects with automatic storage duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464520/using-of-smart-pointers-on-objects-with-automatic-storage-duration)

Answer (score 1):

```
ChildNode child;
Node node;
node.addChild(&child);
```

`addChild()` constructs a `std::unique_ptr` from this passed-in pointer.

The sole reason for having `std::unique_ptr`, and the only reason it exists, is so that `new`ed objects get automatically `delete`d, to prevent memory leaks. That's its entire mission statement.

`std::unique_ptr` (and `std::shared_ptr` too) is not for pointers to objects that are declared in automatic scope, and which will be automatically destroyed when the automatic scope ends. If you are not creating objects with `new` there is absolutely no reason, whatsoever, to use `std::unique_ptr`. It does not accomplish anything except to create bugs and memory errors, of this sort.

You'll either need to remove all use of `std::unique_ptr` (since it doesn't do anything, and only creates problems here), or create all objects with `new` before assigning their ownership to a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: In addition, rather than using `new`, use `std::make_unique`.  (There's another use case for unique_ptr, which can have a customer deleter, used for post-op clean-up.  But that's not relevant for the OP's use case.)